# "The certificate has expired" from PayPal sandbox

Tags: ssl, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm in the process of integrating PayPal payments through Cybersource API. When I click on the button returned from the latter I got redirected to PayPal sandbox website and I'm shown the following error:

[image]

> The certificate has expired. Please use a valid certificate.

I contacted Cybersouce support but they have not found anything wrong with my test account.

I know about [recent changes](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US) in PayPal, but I don't know how relevant this is to my problem.

This error seems to pop up on various e-commerce sites when clients complain about not being able to pay with PayPal. Unfortunately none of those places mentioned what was the fix.

Can anyone at least point me to the direction I should be looking for a solution? Which certificate this error mentions? Is that the API certificate for SOAP integrations as mentioned [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1953&viewlocale=en_US)?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was referring to the expired certificates Cert ID, You need to consider new Cert ID after uploading new certificate to Paypal.

[image]

[This](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0PD04Y) link will walk you through the process.